# AWS EKS - aws-node daemonset fails after launching successfully

Tags: amazon-eks

I have AWS EKS cluster with 3 nodes. I am facing couple of issues.

1.The worker nodes joins the cluster and after some time one of the nodes goes down . The aws-node daemonset fails in one or more of the cluster.  Describing the pod i get

Events:
 Type     Reason   Age                  From                                                  Message
 ----     ------   ----                 ----                                                  -------
 Warning  BackOff  2m (x2949 over 10h)  kubelet, ip-XXX-XXX-4-184.us-west-2.compute.internal  Back-off restarting failed container

2.Have 2 pods(2 applications) in the same worker node where both pods communicates with external services. Where asone could communicate and the other could not. 
Kubectl get po  returns both pods as available .